# Serilog static Logger does not log after IHost.Run()

Tags: c#, serilog, asp.net-core-5.0

I am using Serilog (Serilog.AspNetCore, Version 4.0.0) in an ASP.Net Core 5 application.
It works fine for the most part, but now I've noticed that the static logger in Program.cs doesn't log anything after the IHost.Run method terminates (either regularly or by an exception).

I'm trying to incorporate option validation by implementing the IValidateOptions interface.
This works so far: if an option is invalid, an OptionsValidationException is thrown and the program flow jumps to the corresponding catch branch in the Main method. There, however, the errors are not written to the logfile.
The debugger showed that at that point all loglevels are suddenly disabled, although they were still correctly enabled before the IHost.Run method was executed.

Here is my code:

```
Program.cs:

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        IHost host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        // this is logged, debugger shows that log levels are correctly enabled
        Log.Information("Logging message in Main, before IHost.Run() - this works.");
        host.Run();
    }
    catch (OptionsValidationException ex)
    {
        // this is never logged, debugger shows that all log levels are disabled
        Log.Information("Just check if this is logged - no, it is not logged.");
        Log.Fatal("Options validation failed. Please review the configuration (appsettings.json and appsettings.internal.json).");
        Log.Fatal("Failing option is {FailingOptionsName}", ex.OptionsName);
        foreach (string msg in ex.Failures)
        {
            Log.Fatal(msg);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // this is never logged, debugger shows that all log levels are disabled
        Log.Fatal(ex, "Application start-up failed");
    }
    finally
    {
        // this is never logged, debugger shows that all log levels are disabled
        Log.Information("Shutdown logger");
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    BuildConfiguration();
    CreateLogger();
    Log.Information("Application startup ...");

    IHostBuilder hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
    {
        loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
            .Enrich.With(new ThreadIdEnricher());
    });

    return hostBuilder
    .UseWindowsService()
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseConfiguration(Configuration);
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();

        webBuilder.UseHttpSys(options =>
        {
            ...
        });
    });
}

private static void BuildConfiguration()
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}

private static void CreateLogger()
{
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
            .Enrich.With(new ThreadIdEnricher()).CreateLogger();
    Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(Console.Out);
    Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Out = Console.Out;
    Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.WriteLine("Write to selflog");
}
```

and here the serilog part from appsettings.json:

```
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Verbose"
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" },
      {
        "Name": "Async",
        "Args": {
          "configure": [
            {
              "Name": "File",
              "Args": {
                "path": "Logs/WebDAVLog-.log",
                "rollingInterval": "Day",
                "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} ({ThreadID}) [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                "retainedFileCountLimit": 5,
                "shared": true
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

I also tried to enable Serilog's selflogging (see CreateLogger method), but more than the one line I output there directly ("Write to selflog") is not logged even with that.

1. What do I have to do so that the log messages are written correctly to the logfile after the IHost.Run method?
2. What do I have to do to switch on the SelfLog of Serilog correctly?

Comment: UseSerilog replaces the static logger. At least, one of the optional boolean arguments to it controls how that works. Might wanna take a look at that if you haven't

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 It's been a while, but for the sake of completeness: Your comment helped me to solve the issue, especially the hint that UseSerilog replaces the static logger. If you post your comment as an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: I have the same problem. I use Net6 and nlog. Did you figure out whats going on?